# Power BI Visual showing Time Series Average Excluding Sliced Value and the Value Separately

Tags: powerbi, dax, average

I would like to create a visual that shows the average value for all my series in a fact table, and have a slicer that, when utilized, the data set sliced is REMOVED from the average and shown separately. The point of this is to answer "this series compares to the average of the other series, without including itself, in this way."

I can't decide if this can be done in DAX (which I'm still new to ) or would require a calculated table. I performed the feat in excel using sumifs / countifs, and then graphing that next to what is being excluded. I'm sure it's not hard...

Here's the simple data

| Date | Person | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | Bob | 140 |
| 1/1/2023 | Sarah | 125 |
| 1/1/2023 | Sam | 140 |
| 1/1/2023 | Alex | 155 |
| 2/1/2023 | Bob | 50 |
| 2/1/2023 | Sarah | 185 |
| 2/1/2023 | Sam | 200 |
| 2/1/2023 | Alex | 215 |
| 3/1/2023 | Bob | 230 |
| 3/1/2023 | Sarah | 245 |
| 3/1/2023 | Sam | 260 |
| 3/1/2023 | Alex | 275 |
| 4/1/2023 | Bob | 290 |
| 4/1/2023 | Sarah | 305 |
| 4/1/2023 | Sam | 320 |
| 4/1/2023 | Alex | 335 |
| 5/1/2023 | Bob | 350 |
| 5/1/2023 | Sarah | 365 |
| 5/1/2023 | Sam | 380 |
| 5/1/2023 | Alex | 395 |

and here's the result in excel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create two measures similar to:

```
Avg Not Selected = 
  var selectedPerson =
    CALCULATETABLE(
      DISTINCT('YourTable'[Person]),
      ALLSELECTED('YourTable'[Person])
    )
  return
    CALCULATE(
      AVERAGE('YourTable'[Score]),
      NOT ISFILTERED('YourTable'[Person]) ||
      NOT 'YourTable'[Person] IN selectedPerson
    )


Avg Selected = 
  var hasSelection =
    CALCULATE(
      ISFILTERED('YourTable'[Person]),
      ALLSELECTED('YourTable'[Person])
    )
  var result = AVERAGE('YourTable'[Score])
  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    hasSelection, result,
    NOT ISBLANK(result), 0
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @sam nseir

This does exactly what i asked for. Follow on question; if no one "person" is selected in the slicer, how would i make the bar part of the chart go away and the line show the average of the whole table? in current configuration, unselected everyone sums their "score" in the bar table, and the line goes away.   thank you

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting errors about displaying the visual. This is what I tried:

AverageNotSelected = 
 var SelectedPerson = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        DISTINCT('YourTable'[Person]),
        ALLSELECTED('YourTable'[Person])
     )

  return
        if(not selectedperson = "",
            CALCULATE(
                AVERAGE('YourTable'[Score]),
                NOT 'YourTable'[Person] IN selectedPerson
            ),
            AVERAGE('YourTable'[Score])
        )

I tried moving the "if(not selectedperson) to use a <> instead of the "not" but that didn't work

Comment: Updated answer above to leverage `ISFILTERED(...)`. Unfortunately, `Avg Selected` needs to return a value otherwise the whole chart won't render.

Comment: Thank you. When i create the new measures above and unselect a value, the line chart extends out on the X Axis to december with no data on the Y. Any idea why or how to cause it to only show X axis for where data exits? I tried creating a calendar table, joining the two, and plotting the date of the calendar on the X axis, but it still shows a line that stops where it should and the x axis continues on. It does this only when no "person" is selected. I'm guessing its not inheriting real data from the fact table and that causes the date overflow, but don't know how to cure.

Comment: Updated `Avg Selected` to only return 0 if there is data.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment as it didn't make sense and i figured out why i was confused. thanks

Comment: Problem solved? If so please help mark answer as Accepted for the benefit of all.